# Помогите понять работу foreach

Tags: php

Возникла проблема с `foreach`. Если делаю так:

```
foreach ($formarray as $form) {
    var_dump($form)
}
var_dump($formarray);
```

получаю:

```
string(56) "REUwaFZtQ0ggAlE3DC9zcTYgBTkPPDllE3BxEBM1MCYPB2YZOih0OQ=="
array(7) {
    ["_csrf"]=> string(56) "REUwaFZtQ0ggAlE3DC9zcTYgBTkPPDllE3BxEBM1MCYPB2YZOih0OQ=="
    ["title"]=> string(3) "qqq"
    ["description"]=> string(4) "qwer"
    ["allow"]=> string(1) "0"
    ["userid"]=> string(0) ""
    ["date"]=> string(10) "1452063008"
    ["productid"]=> string(1) "1"
}
```

Подскажите, почему так получается?

Comment: var_dump($form) в этой строке ; не хватает как минимум. И поясните, что должно получится? Насколько я понимаю в цикле вы выводите дамп всех значений массива $formarray. А затем дамп самого массива.

Comment: @Dmitry OnGamer если я правильно понимаю дампы должны быть одинаковые нет ? Я просто пытаюсь вывести к примеру var_dump($form["title"])  что бы получилось string(3) 'qqq'? А получаю null

Comment: в данном случае дампы не будут одинаковыми, т.к. вы используете конструкцию $formarray as $form, т.е. перебор всех значений массива $formarray. Корректней эту конструкцию записать так $formarray as $value. Можете сразу записать var_dump($formarray['title']) без цикла.

Comment: @Dmitry OnGamer А в чем разница между  $formarray as $form и $formarray as $value? Хорошо, а как мне вывести все значения к примеру как мне получить к примеру значение ключа  ['title'] масива  $formarray ещё раз вот так я пробовал $form['title']  дало null

Comment: @Dmitry OnGamer получаю Illegal string offset 'title'

Comment: разницы с точки зрения исполнения кода нет, это просто для удобства чтения кода. записью  $form['title'] в теле цикла, вы обращаетесь сразу к очередному значению массива, в вашем случае к строке, с инструкцией найти в строке какой-то ключ! WTF? Конечно там будет null

Comment: @Sergalas Люди частенько задавая тут вопросы сокращают код, чтоб упростить. В итоге, как оказывается, проблемы скрываются именно вне этого кода и нужен полный код. Вы приведите пример побольше, где поясняется что вы делаете, какие данные испльзуются, зачем и каков хотите чтоб был итог.... конкретнее примеры)

Comment: http://www.php.su/learnphp/cs/?cycles#foreach

Comment: Откуда берётся  `$formarray`? Может, это не "честный" массив, а массивоподобный объект какой-нибудь, где часть свойств недоступны итератору, и поэтому не видны для `foreach`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выведет дампы всех ключей массива `$formarray`

```
foreach ($formarray as $key=>$value) {
   var_dump($key);
}
```

Выведет дампы всех значений массива `$formarray`

```
foreach ($formarray as $key=>$value) {
   var_dump($value);
}
```

или

```
foreach ($formarray as $value) {
   var_dump($value);
}
```

Цикл `foreach` оперирует не исходным массивом, а его копией. Это означает, что любые изменения, которые вносятся в массив, не могут быть "видны" из тела цикла.
http://www.php.su/learnphp/cs/?cycles#foreach

Если Вы хотите получить дамп значения, какого либо ключа отдельно, то это можно сделать вне тела цикла

```
var_dump($formarray['ключ']);
```

Comment: вопрос ОП не о том, почему в цикле выведено только первое значение, хотя в массиве их больше?

Comment: судя по комментариям, нет). да и сложно представить ситуацию в рамках приведенного кода, когда массивы просто разные.

Comment: похоже, всё проще, вы правы  : )

Comment: осталось загадкой даже для меня, какая часть ответа решила проблему автора)

Answer (score 1):

Надо бы уточнить, откуда берётся `$formarray`?

Похожий эффект можно получить с `ArrayObject`:

```
class Example {
    public $public = 'prop:public';
    private $prv   = 'prop:private';
    protected $prt = 'prop:protected';
}
$arrayobj = new ArrayObject(new Example());

foreach($arrayobj AS $value) var_dump($value);
var_dump($arrayobj);
```

Выведет:

```
string(11) "prop:public"
object(ArrayObject)#1 (1) {
  ["storage":"ArrayObject":private]=>
  object(Example)#2 (3) {
    ["public"]=> string(11) "prop:public"
    ["prv":"Example":private]=> string(12) "prop:private"
    ["prt":protected]=> string(14) "prop:protected"
  }
}
```

Т.е. приватные свойства не видны для `foreach`.